# React scrollIntoView create a margin on the bottom of the page

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, js-scrollintoview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QubIZ.png)current.scrollIntoView in the app some strange margin apears on the bottom of the page and push the content up.
This is the code:

```js
 const scrollInmask = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (inmask && inmask.current) {
        inmask.current.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'auto',
          block: 'center',
          inline: 'center',
        });
      }
    }, );
  }
```